# SSH client not launching in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HusF.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUQwa.png)

I am using aws and I went to AWS marketplace and selected PArse as a free tier. then i Launched it and created a key And saved it. THen i treid to connect it by passing the key information but the SSH CLIENT does not launch. i have tried many other keys as well but it is not launching.Help?

Answer (score 0):

I recall the Java client has issues on a number of browsers.

An alternative would be to install an SSH client and launch that yourself and then start your connection. You appear to be using windows so I recommend using [Putty](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html). You should be able to read the Putty documentation to get started, however a quick summary of what you need to do is.

Put the value Public DNS in the domain/host field and point to your keys in the configuration.